# AES Decryption in Java takes too long

Tags: java, performance, api, tomcat, encryption

I have a piece of Java code in an API which uses AES and 256 bit passphrase to decrypt a string. Once it is decrypted, it is used as password to connect to a database.

This API is deployed on tomcat on Red Hat Linux. The issue is that the decryption process it taking too long (approx 15 mins) for most of the requests. 1 out of 5 requests are instantaneous. I do not store the decrypted key anywhere. Any idea why some requests take long time and some take few milliseconds?

The annoying part is that, i have another API deployed in the same tomcat with the same length passphrase and it just takes few milliseconds to decrypt.

Comment: Show the code. That's the best way to get great answers.

Answer (score 3):

This can be related to insufficient *entropy*, try with this system property : `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom`

As explained in a [redhat bug 118921](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=118921), this command should show if you have an entropy problem (it will hang) :

```
dd if=/dev/random of=testfile bs=1 count=1
```

Comment: Why would a DE-crypt need entropy?

Answer (score 0):

There was a hung thread in tomcat which was causing an issue. I restarted the tomcat service and now it is fine.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions.